# Can I have a form on index.php and process it with index.php

Tags: php

Is this possible? I have looked online and cannot seem to find an answer.

Comment: what is your mean?? forms can be in php files and can be proccess with it, it`s a usual happen!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes why not

sure you can post to the same page :)

INDEX.PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['txt']))
 echo 'Thnx for submitting the form';
else
 echo 'Submit the form';
?>
<form name="frm" method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txt"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this :) has explained it better.

Answer (score 2):

yes,

```
 <form name="name" method="post" action="">
```

then run the php to handle the data in the top of index.php

Answer (score 0):

This not exactly what you asked for but this will make your form submit to its own page without reloading the page so here is the link. It's a youtube video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPXL-ZU3rEY&feature=related